# installing job submission management (eg slurm) on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: scheduler

My lab is currently working with an ubuntu based distribution in 20.04 on a machine with 72 cores. We'd like to setup a job scheduler so we could submit computing jobs to each of the different cores. I've gone through the [slurm quickstart](https://slurm.schedmd.com/quickstart.html) but have not managed to get it to work. I can't get the daemon to start. Previously my lab used the TORQUE job scheduler by [installing an older version as described here](https://jabriffa.wordpress.com/2015/02/11/installing-torquepbs-job-scheduler-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts/). I have yet to try installing TORQUE on this machine because the packages aren't showing up with apt-get and installing all the dependencies seems difficult manually. Has anyone managed to get a job scheduler to work?

Comment: Can you please add details with output what you tried and what error you get ?

Comment: I found that one can install it with Synaptic Package Manager.  The advantage is that it installs all the correct dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I found snap install at https://snapcraft.io/install/slurm/ubuntu
But it is not clear where to put the slurm.conf file?

Comment: Please reply to this comment if you ever figure out where to put the slurm.conf file, and I will upvote this answer.

Comment: /var/snap/slurm/common/etc/slurm/slurm.conf